# Why Won't my jQuery Play Nice with Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, shortcode

Code in question here: http://pastebin.com/PN29WKNq

It worked on the HTML page I tested it on.  Its supposed to add "display: none" to the content divs and then add "display: block" when the appropriate tab is clicked.  But it just changes to "display: none" and never changes.

Comment: Just a quick note : did you try the noConflict mode ? It's safer to use jQuery instead of the $ in your jQuery code, as WP uses it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress automatically loads jQuery in "no conflict" mode so that it will be compatible with other libraries.  This means the `$` variable ***isn't used for jQuery*** within WordPress.

Rewrite your code to use the full jQuery keyword when you begin your closure like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    // ... other code in here

});
```

This is functionally the same as `$(document).ready(function() {` but uses the full name of the jQuery object to avoid noConflict issues.  By passing jQuery in to the closure as the `$` variable you can then use `$` like normal *inside* the closure.

Comment: I updated my code to this:    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... but it still doesn't work.  I have no doubt thats what you're supposed to do but the jquery isn't working the way it did on the html page

Comment: Are you `enqueue`ing jQuery?  I can't see your full script ... so all I can help troubleshoot is what I have access to.

Comment: The full script is what I showed you in the pastebin.  Its the only script I have.

Comment: No, I mean *all* of your code.  All of the PHP and JS you're using to try to use this.  The code you showed in the pastebin had *both* JS and PHP cobbled together and didn't show where you were using what.

Comment: What part of the theme do you need to see?  Its all pretty standard.  The PHP code is from my functions.php for a shortcode and the jQuery is in its own main.js file.

Comment: How are you queuing your scripts? Is jQuery loaded? Is it loaded before your `main.js` file? Can you use the Firebug/Chrome/Safari console to verify that it's working? There's nothing wrong with your actual code if you changed it as I suggested above ... so something else is going on.

Comment: I've linked to my script and the jquery google code page in the header.php file (between the head tags).  The script is working as in I can click a tab and the previously open tab goes to "display: none".  My problem is getting the tabs to "display: block" when they're activated.  They do it fine in the HTML but not on Wordpress.

Comment: OK, in that case, you're going to need to provide some more detail and possibly access to your site.  I'd recommend the [WP.org support forums](http://wordpress.org/support) for that kind of thing.  It seems like something's going on with your site, but we can't debug it without actually seeing it ... and since WPSE isn't a support forum, I'm gonna point you back to WP.org.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help and patience through this!

Answer (score -2):

Try putting this in your functions.php file in your theme folder:

```
function load_jquery() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.5/jquery.min.js', false, '1.8.5');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'load_jquery');
```

You could also use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/use-google-libraries/